# Harwell-Boeing format for sparse matrices

Tags: libraries

I'm dealing with SVDLIBC library. In order to compute singular values I need to specify my matrix in the Harwell-Boeing format. On Internet I have found next example:

Dense Text Format:

```
4 3

2.3  0  4.2

0   1.3 2.2

3.8  0  0.5

0    0   0
```

Sparse Text Harwell-Boeing Format:

SVDLIBC v. 1.32

```
3             1             1             1             0
rra     
              4             3             6             0

       (8i)            (8i)            (8e)            (8e)

1 3 4 7 

1 3 2 1 2 3 

2.3 3.8 1.3 4.2 2.2 0.5
```

In other libraries for sparse matrices I specified matrix as an array of non-zero values and their indices, but I can't understand how do they specify matrix in Harwell-Boeing format. Can anybody explain me how do they form two array of indices in an example above? I'm a newcomer in this field, so I'm sorry if the question seems too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Harwell-Boeing Format is described [here](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html).